# Edit mode bevel cylindrical hole, loop slide only work on a subset of edges

Tags: edges, bevel, loop

When trying to bevel in edit mode, [the loop slide feature as described in the documentation](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/modeling/meshes/editing/edge/bevel.html), only applies to some edges. Demonstrated in the attached image. I have no idea what distinguishes the edges where the bevel collides with the outside edge from the edges that bevel as intended.

[image]

[Here is the .blend file from the screenshot.](https://drive.google.com/file/d/11t1_uBaSi9rp6QQ11PTMJSIQjPeGc27i/view?usp=sharing)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Please describe what you're trying to achieve, as I suspect this question could be the [XY Problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XY_problem).

Dealing with the problem literally, a vertex of the outer loop of the bevel follows (slides on) the edge connected to that loop, and in case of some edges, it therefore changes a lot where it would normally move; if the edge connecting with vertex **A** of the outerloop is parallel to the edge going from **A** downwards, then there's no change between loop slide enabled and disabled:

[image]

You're probably about to hit another problem due to having ngons not surrounded by co-planar faces. You can fix it by rearranging middle edge loops to be as far from the holes as possible (exactly in-between them), selecting one of ngons, <kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>G</kbd>, *Coplanar*, then <kbd>I</kbd> inset:

[image]

Comment: The issue was that some edges would bevel neatly and some wouldn't. I expected the loop slide function was involved. Your inset suggestions fixed the issue, everything now bevels smoothly. Thanks for taking the time to solve my poorly phrased question!

Edit: How do you display the bevel options, like in your first screenshot?

Comment: @user2406501 bevel, accept with left-click, then in bottom-left a popup will appear. Expand it and change the settings.